# Option tag with data-* attributes in Django with crispy forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a `ModelMultipleChoiceFiel` field which renders something like this

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option pk="1">something 1</option>
  <option pk="2">something 2</option>
</select>
```

But I would like to add extra `data-*` attributes to the options, so I want the rendered HTML to look something like this

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option pk="1" data-something-from-model="cat">something 1</option>
  <option pk="2" data-something-from-model="dog">something 2</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to do this with crispy forms? If not where should I look in the source code to do it?

(currently I'm rendering it like this `Field("networks", css_class="form-control")`)

Comment: Did you solve it? I have same problems!